# Unable to use my <a href> links from my website to external sites. (i.e. my site to my discord or patreon)

Tags: html

My site is http://inquizgaming.info/

When you click a link here in edge, it gives you a message saying:

"This content can’t be shown in a frame
There is supposed to be some content here, but the publisher doesn’t allow it to be displayed in a frame. This is to help protect the security of any information you might enter into this site.
Try this:
Open this in a new window"

In chrome, the page just stays blank.
This doesn't make a lot of sense to me, as i am not framing (i.e. using ,, or etc.) these links. 
The entire body of the code for that first "Join Discord" button is:

```html
<section id="banner">
  <div class="inner">
      <h2>Inquisitional Gaming</h2>
   <p>An open gaming community for all platforms!</p>
       <ul class="actions">
                            <li><a href="http://discord.gg/qDf8DG9" class="button big alt">Join Our Discord!</a></li><br>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </section>
```

And from this, i just can't seem to understand what the issue is. I've been looking all over online. I am new to html, css, and JS. I am a novice at website building, and i am sure the problem is somewhere im not thinking of.

EDIT: When i right-click (or hold on mobile) and open it in a new window, the link works fine. This is EXTREMELY frustrating.

Comment: The entire web site is in a frame. You can see that if you right click anywhere and choose "View page source". You'll have to sort it out with your service provider.

Comment: if you are ok with open this page in new tab you can do that. use code <a href="http://discord.gg/qDf8DG9" class="button big alt" target="_blank">Join Our Discord!</a> or you have sort it out with service provider

Comment: as @JJJ said, your site is an iframe from `http://68.185.245.9/`, if you go there, your Links work just fine. Make sure, that `inquizgaming.info` is an `A` DNS-record pointing to whatever IP Adress you use to host your content (on XAMPP on a Windows 32bit System, don't do that ^^ )

Comment: Thank you all so much for the reply. I believe thanks to you guys, I've learned a good bit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open your site http://inquizgaming.info/ and right-click to inspect the HTML you see the `<frameset border="0" rows="*,1">`.

If you now click on a link on your site, the `discordapp.com` server answers with the HTTP-Header 'X-Frame-Options' set to 'sameorigin'. This Header indicates, that the browser is not allowed to render `https://discordapp.com/invite/qDf8DG9` in the visiting browser.

You can read the details about the the HTTP-Header here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

As you cannot change the HTTP-Response from `discordapp.com`' you need to either remove the all the `<frameset>, <frame> and <iframe>` or you can add a `target="_blank"` attribute to every link referencing the external link.

Answer (score 3):

http://68.185.245.9/ is your host IP. With what I'm gathering, you have an index file linking to your IP which in turn shows your page, but it's linking it with a frame and thus breaks the ability for your links to redirect you. Have your service provider reconfigure your DNS so it has an `A` record pointing towards your host IP.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the link in a new window, and the link works perfectly fine, then try adding this to your `<a>` tag...

```
<a href="http://discord.gg/qDf8DG9" class="button big alt" target="_blank">Join Our Discord!</a>
```

The `target="_blank"` attribute tells the browser to open the link in a new window.  Also, it's good practice to place out-going links (that contain content not specific to your website) in a new window.

---

EDIT:  As others have said, your website code is placed within several `<frame>` tags.  Some functionalities, such as the `<a>` tag, will behave differently.  Inspecting your website (using developer's tools by pressing Ctrl+Shift+I on Chrome or Firefox) will show the firstmost tags being `<frame>` containers.

Comment: No, it's not a good practice. Let the user decide if he wants to open it in a new window, using the default behaviour of the browser.

Comment: I mean, you're not "technically" wrong, but this probably isn't the answer OP is looking for.